# What is the best practice to connect flutter with firebase?

Tags: firebase, flutter

I started to work with flutter and firebase (mostly firestore and auth). Are there any good practise to use firebase in flutter project? I mean does firebase have to be a singleton or can I create multiple instance? A Firebase doc are quite empty when it comes to flutter :/

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Answer (score 0):

All Firebase services are already implemented as singletons, i.e.

```
Firestore.instance
```

and

```
FirebaseAuth.instance
```

I recommend checking out the documentation of both for more info and examples:

- Firestore [docs](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/Firestore-class.html) and [example](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/cloud_firestore/example/lib/main.dart)
- FirebaseAuth [docs](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseAuth/instance.html) and [example](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/firebase_auth/example)